# Loading .gdbinit from current directory fails with "auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path'"

Tags: gdb, gdbinit

I'm having trouble loading a .gdbinit file located in the current directory. On starting gdb, I get this:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
warning: File "/home/user1/test/.gdbinit" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
```

I can load the .gdbinit file in the current directory by starting gdb with:

```
gdb -iex 'add-auto-load-safe-path .'
```

as described [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto_002dloading-safe-path.html). but is there a way set $debugdir to include the current directory?

Trying

```
$ export debugdir=.
$ gdb
```

yields the same warning as above.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html#Init%20File%20in%20the%20Current%20Directory%20during%20Startup

Basically, what you want is to allow loading the per-directory .gdbinit from your ~/.gdbinit.  If you are not worried about the security aspects, then this works:

```
set auto-load safe-path .
```

Or, if that doesn't cut it for some reason, you can also allow loading the `.gdbinit` from anywhere on the system:

```
set auto-load safe-path /
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Setting the auto-load safe-path in the home directory .gdbinit worked. Setting the safe-path to . instead of / also worked. This would be more secure, no?

Comment: Yeah, for the most security, set this to the minimal things required.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had no `~/.gdbinit` file. The solution was creating this file containing two lines specifying auto-load-safe-path(s).

```
add-auto-load-safe-path <path1>
add-auto-load-safe-path <path2>
```