# Make gdb read project specific .gdbinit when using Qt Creator

Tags: gdb, qt-creator, gdbinit

`~/.gdbinit` is loaded when I start a remote debugging session from Qt Creator.

How can I force gdb to load a project specific `.gdbinit` file?

I've added this line to `~/.gdbinit`

```
set auto-load local-gdbinit on
```

and added an additional `.gdbinit` file to my project directory and to the build output directory, but gdb seems to ignore both.

The manual for `local-gdbinit` says, that when set to `on`, gdb will look for a `.gdbinit` in the current directory. But I can't even figure out what the current directory is once Qt Creator starts `gdb`, so I'm pretty lost.

In another failed attempt (as found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16742034/1300910)) I've added this to `~/.gdbinit`

```
set auto-load safe-path /
```

Qt Creator version is 2.7.1, gdb version is 7.4-2012.04.

Comment: I guess the directory from where the debugger is run is set under "Projects", "Run" configuration in "Working directory" field. You should be able to find that out with `pwd` command in "Debugger Log" view in Qt Creator.

Comment: Since I'm remote debugging, "Working directory" points to a directory on the remote machine, so impossible gdb would load .gdbinit from there. `pwd` results in `/home/user/Documents` which is not project specific, any ideas on how I can tell Qt Creator to start gdb from the build output directory?

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing remote debugging as well, and I looked at the "Debugger Log" view's output from `pwd` and the working directory was set to the directory I specified in the "Attach to Remote Debugger" dialog. I don't think the local working directory has anything to do with the remote working directory in this case.

I then just set up my ~/.gdbinit to add my source directory to the auto-load safe-path and auto-load local-gdbinit on, then put my project-specific custom .gdbinit in my source directory and it just worked, at least for me.

Comment: but you did put an absolute path in `~/.gdbinit` then?

Comment: No, I didn't, except for the the auto-load safe-path, which was something along the lines of /home/me/workspaces