# Project/Folder specific breakpoints in gdb

Tags: gdb

I'd like to set a set of breakpoints for a certain project to be loaded up when gdb starts. Until now I've been using ~/.gdbinit to hold those breakpoints, however, they are quite tedious to manage when using gdb with another project. Is there a way I can create gdb configurations custom to each project?

Comment: You can have `gdb` load `.gdb_init` from the current directory. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595417/loading-gdbinit-from-current-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load any script with -x switch. So, gdb -x projectconfig.gdb yourbinary.

Projectconfig.gdb would contain what you initially had in .gdb_init.